# duplicating window when pressing button

Tags: python, user-interface, window, pysimplegui

I'm trying to develop a script that would open a new window by clicking on the duplicate button and close it by clicking on close. I'm using the PySimpleGUI libaray. However, I encounter several errors. Here is my script:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
n = 0
layout = [[sg.Text("Duplicate or close?")], [sg.Button("close")], [sg.Button("duplicate")]]
print(n)
# Create the window
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)

# Create an event loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    # End program if user closes window or
    # presses the OK button
    if event == "close" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        window.close()
        
    if event == "duplicate" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        n = [[sg.Text("Duplicate or close?")], [sg.Button("close")], [sg.Button("duplicate")]]
        window = sg.Window("Demo", n)
        n += 1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/GeliMorto/Documents/gui.py", line 19, in <module>
    n += 1
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I've tried to make it whit an unique window layout:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
n = 0
layout = [[sg.Text("Duplicate or close?")], [sg.Button("close")], [sg.Button("duplicate")]]
```

But that did not work
So i have done that at every loop the layout name changes.
And i have the error i have writed on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following statement, `n` will be a List, how can it `n += 1` ? Maybe replace it with different variable name, like `layout`.

```py
n = [[sg.Text("Duplicate or close?")], [sg.Button("close")], [sg.Button("duplicate")]]
```

There's still issue about how you to close any opened window ? You didn't save all the old windows to do any action in the future , like `close` the window.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_window(index):
    layout = [[sg.Text("duplicate or close?"), sg.Button("close"), sg.Button("duplicate"), sg.Button('close all')]]
    return sg.Window(f'Window #{index}', layout)

window = new_window(0)
windows = [window]
index = 0

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'close'):
        window.close()
        del windows[-1]
        index -= 1
        if windows:
            window = windows[-1]
            window.un_hide()
        else:
            break

    elif event == 'duplicate':
        window.hide()
        index += 1
        window = new_window(index)
        windows.append(window)

    elif event == 'close all':
        for window in windows:
            window.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is come code that opens multiple windows and close them:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import copy

master_layout = [[sg.Text("Duplicate or close?",s=50)],
                 [sg.Button("close", key='-CLOSE-')], 
                 [sg.Button("duplicate", k='-DUPLICATE-')]]
windows = {} # diction to hold all window items return from sg.window
windowCount = 1

#create the first window
layout = copy.deepcopy(master_layout)
layout.insert(0,[sg.Text(f"Window {windowCount} of {len(windows)+1}",k='tile')])
window = windows[f"Window{windowCount}"] = sg.Window(f"Demo #{windowCount}", layout, finalize=True)

# Create an event loop for all windows
while True:
    if len(windows) == 0:
        break # all windows are closed
    windowKeys = list(windows.keys()) #capture the keys at this moment to avoid the error of dictinary changed size during iteration
    for curWindow in windowKeys: #check each open window for an event    
        event, values = windows[curWindow].read(timeout=10)
        if event == '__TIMEOUT__':
            continue
        print (f"Window Event from {curWindow}:",event,"   Values:",values)
        if event == "-CLOSE-" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            windows[curWindow].close()     # End program if user closes window or
            windows.pop(curWindow) #remove the closed window from the list of open Windows
        elif event == "-DUPLICATE-":
            windowCount += 1 #increase the count of windows
            layout = copy.deepcopy(master_layout)
            layout.insert(0,[sg.Text(f"Window {windowCount} of {len(windows)+1}",k='tile')])
            windows[f"Window{windowCount}"] = sg.Window(f"Demo #{windowCount}", layout, finalize=True)
```

A few challenges were the Error creating Window layout -> broken the layout reuse rule?

[image]

I solved this by deep coping my master_layout to layout variable I used each time I opened a new window.

The next challenge was making sure I read the events for every window I opens, so I create a dictionary of windows and had a loop that went through each window to read it for events for a timeout=10 milliseconds.

The third challenge was that python complaining that when dictionary of windows changed while i was iterating through the list of keys in my windows dictionary; therefore I create a temporary list keys of the windows dictionary of opened windows and iterated through that temporary list.